# First fundamental theorem of calculus: integration range

Tags: calculus

On Wikipedia I find:

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x$ in $[a, b]$, by

$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$.

Why is it necessary that the lower integration range is $a$? It could be any fixed value in $[a,b]$ or do I overlook something?

Comment: It is not necessary.... It is just defined like this

Comment: Why is it necessary for *what*?  It could be any fixed value in $[a,b]$ for *what* to happen?  We could define $F(x)$ as the price to go to the zoo if we wanted to.  But there is probably a *reason* we are doing this.  But otherwise we can define things any way we want.

Comment: Okay, in context: "t could be any fixed value in [a,b]"  Yes, it *could* be any value.  But it has to be *some* value. So why *not* $a$?  It's useful and simplest to have $F(a) = 0$ and $F(b) = \int_a^b f(x)dx$.  We will always have the "plus a constant" issue and this makes it simplest with the constant being $F(a) = 0$.

Comment: There's no loss of generality in starting the integration at the left endpoint of the interval. If $a < c < b$, then $f$ is continuous on $[c,b]$, so you can equally well define $F(x) = \int_c^x f(t)\ dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary.

Suppose $f$ is continuous and defined on some continuous connected interval. If we let $c$ and $d$  be any arbitrary points in that interval and we define two functions for a variable $x$ within the domain of that continuous connected interval as:

$G(x) = \int_c^x f(x) dx$ and $H(x) = \int_d^x f(x) dx$ then

$\int_c^d f(x)dx$ is a constant value.  We can call it $C_1$.

ANd $G(x) =\int_c^x f(x) dx = \int_c^d f(x) dx + \int_d^x f(x) dx = H(x) + C_1$ and

Now if either of these functions were differentiable we would have that both are and

$G'(x) = H'(x)$.

So far, none of that is particularly interesting.

What *is* interesting and important is that, *yes*, both the functions *are* differentiable and that by some amazing twist of math

> $G'(x) = H'(x)$ turns out to actually equal the function $f(x)$ itself.

That is an integral acts and is equal to the "anti-derivative".

And that's the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

So.... what is the best way to express that with the least amount of irrelevant and vague details?

Well we don't need *two* anchoring point, we just need $a$.  So for $a$ in some connected interval within which $f$ is continuous is sufficient.

And the "on some continuous connected interval" is vague.  On that is necessary is that $a$ be in that interval.  It's sufficient to just claim that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ for some $b \ge a$.

ANd that's really it..

It's true that it might be continuous on a larger open interval or on the entire reals but there is some, not necessarily distinguishable, closed interval to limit our definition to.

And it may be true that any point in any interval can be our "anchor point" but it is sufficient to just pick the lower endpoint of the interval.